# Adjective for someone who is really good at cooking or baking and/or bakes frequently

Tags: adjectives

So and so is the most "bakiest" person I know! She's so good at baking!

What word could feasibly replace "bakiest" which I obviously made up. :)

Comment: You would use "best baker", as in "so and so is the best baker I know"

Comment: King or queen of baking.  (Queen, apparently.)

Comment: so and so is the most "capable baker" I know.

Comment: But that doesn't sound as fun!

Comment: She's like a bakery in a dress...

Comment: *She's the Derek Jeter of pastries!*

Comment: *She's the patiserrie-est!*

Comment: @bib :) I would say she's like the Sidney Crosby of baking (Yes, I am Canadian)

Comment: Are you looking for a coined expression, or are you interested in an existing expression/adjective? Usually you say someone is "an excellent" cook/baker/chef. But it seems  you want an adjective that is connected with cuisine in some way. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

*When it comes to baking, she [takes the cake](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/take-the-cake)!*

> Surpass or exceed all others [*Oxford Dictionaries Online*]

Comment: Flagged for being an appalling pun. :)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Actually, it's not a pun but an idiom. In this case, the idiom uses a figurative image that directly relates to the actual situation. If it is perceived as humorous, it's because the relationship between the idiom and the real circumstances are usually somewhat incongruous, but in this case, they are ironically congruous.

Answer (score 1):

The general adjective would be ***dexterous*** (or *dextrous*) because you need skilled hands to be good at cooking and baking. Dexterous is not usually used directly to describe a person who is good at cooking, it is used to emphasize cooking skills within the context; so it wouldn't be an exact fit for your example but you can rephrase your sentence.

> Showing or having skill, especially with the hands
>
> [[oxforddictionaries]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dexterous?q=dextrous)

Example usages from Google Books:

> No one could have imagined that cooking could be a key aspect of dramatic attraction: this drama details cooking procedures from selecting and preparing materials to cutting, steaming, and decorating the food, all presented in fast changing close-up shots catching the colorfulness of the food and **the cook's dexterous skills**, accompanied by cheerful music and sound effects.
>
> [Cultural Studies Of Transnationalis *edited by Handel Kashope Wright, Meaghan Morris, Professor of Cultural Studies Meaghan Morris* - 2013]
>
> ---
>
> There was a certain artistic quality  to the precise movements of the bakers upstairs, the way they pushed slats of “doughs” into the ever-rotating carousel inside the ovens, and then flipped them, and then later removed them, but Rick assured me that Mr. H was the **best, fastest, most dexterous baker** at H&H and that he had once stayed up for twenty-four hours helping bake a special order, which then he single-handedly drove down to Philadelphia on no sleep.
>
> [How to Be a Man: Scenes from a Protracted Boyhood *By Thomas Beller* - 2010]
>
> ---
>
> It is true, the teppan restaurants, in which diners sit around a large flat griddle table where foods are cooked by **a dexterous chef**, were first introduced to Japan after World War II as an attraction for Western visitors.
>
> [Chicago's Best Restaurants *by Sherman Kaplan* - 2003]

Example usage from news articles:

> Fortunately, this **dexterous chef** made some time to share his recipe for Belly & Trumpet’s watermelon salad with cashew relish.
>
> <sup>http://www.thedailymeal.com/ask-dfw-expert-best-easy-tailgate-food</sup>
>
> ---
>
> The sensational version at ROOF on theWit Hotel toes the line between timeworn and modern, all thanks to **dexterous pastry chef** Toni Roberts, who proves time and time again that she is one of Chicago's craftiest dessert mavens.
>
> <sup>http://www.diningchicago.com/articles/2014/08/13/sweet-of-the-week-mint-chip-sundae-at-roof</sup>

---

You can also consider the informal British term ***dab hand***. [The adjective form is ***dab-handed*** but it is very uncommon.] It means a person who is very good or expert at doing something. So in our context, the common phrases are:

> dab hand in the kitchen

and

> dab hand at cooking

It is worth to mention this usage because it is both related to skilled hands and expertise. It is a British term but it gained usage in American English also.

Example usages:

> James is a **dab hand at cooking** main courses, meats, vegetables and such. His wife, Sarah, **bakes like an angel** and makes the most amazing pastries, breads and desserts.
>
> [Seeking Truth *by Francesca Hawley* - 2009]
>
> ---
>
> It could well be because of her **dab hand at cooking** great and tasty meals, that memories of being hungry for longer periods fade to the back of my memory, as mother had a definite gift of preparing delicious plates of food for us.
>
> ["The Journey of I & I" *By Jah siSTAR* - 2013]
>
> ---
>
> Devoted to his mother—a stout, forceful hospitality-aholic who laid out stunning buffets of home-prepared breads, salads, cold dishes, roasts, soups, cakes, and sweets for her friends and neighbors—Beard had become a **dab hand in the kitchen** at a young age; by the time he was eight, he was baking his own bread.
>
> [The United States of Arugula: The Sun Dried, Cold Pressed, Dark Roasted, Extra Virgin Story of the American Food Revolution By *David Kamp* - 2009]

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Yes, you are right. I mentioned a general adjective used in this context because it is related to skilled hands. I'm not sure if there is a better adjective related to cooking.

Comment: Well, there are better collocations. Dexterity doesn't spring to mind when I think about my grandmother's cooking and she was superb at making homemade pasta dishes aged 85!

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Dexterous is not usually used directly to describe a person who is good at cooking, it is used in the context to emphasize the skill as you can see in one of the examples that I gave. Is there a better adjective that springs to mind that is related to cooking? You can come up with a lot of collocations of course but OP asked for an adjective.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I updated my answer also to clarify. Thanks for bringing this up.

Comment: I want to upvote but I can't; dexterity really doesn't fit whereas *dab hand* is spot on.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I explained why it wouldn't be an exact fit for OP's example and I added more examples also. Thanks for making me see additional points to improve my answer. Are we cool now? :)

Answer (score 1):

> She is a **master** baker (or [bakeress](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bakeress)).

You could also use the female equivalent, *mistress*, which [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mistress) defines as

> 5). A woman well skilled in anything, or having the mastery over it.

> She is a **mistress** in the kitchen

It has the added advantage of sounding a little naughty too!

Answer (score 0):

Scrumptious-(of food) extremely appetizing or delicious.

(of a person) very attractive.

---

Sounds weird but it definitely makes for a great couple of sentences.

Answer (score 0):

*cordon bleu*

Denoting or relating to the highest class or standard of quality in cookery:
a *cordon bleu* chef.

Definition from  [oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cordon-bleu)